# Send all users commands via email when user logs out

Tags: linux, sendmail

In Linux, is there a way to send an email with user session (e.g. commands) when he quits an SSH or console session?

Comment: What is a session? When they login via SSH, or to the console, or instead only some graphical environment?

Comment: only ssh and console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided you're talking about running a bash shell in interactive mode, if you refer to [Bash Startup Files](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#Bash-Startup-Files), you should be able to trigger some commands through the `~/.bash_logout` file.

In your case, you would do something like piping the shell history to some mail command, such as:

```
history | mail -s "history" foo@bar.com
```

Comment: Thanks! It does the trick, but sends overall history. I've tried to put "history -c" in the ~/.bash_profile but it doesn't help - the history is the same. Do you have any idea how can i make history only log commands from exact session?

Comment: for one use **last** to find out what timeframe to use - which may be tricky when working on multiple tty at one time - and then use **HISTTIMEFORMAT="%d/%m/%y %T "** to put timestamps on the output of **history**.

Comment: [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171341/bash-history-for-current-session) i found

Comment: but it still doesn't work within .bash_profile

Comment: Figured out that running "rm -f ~/.bash_history ; touch ~/.bash_history" in bash_profile and running "history -a" before your command in bash_logout does exactly what i needed it to do.